Is it an invariant in Aave V3 that 1 aUSDC can always be redeemed for 1 USDC?
Say you have some Aave V3 aTokens like aUSDC. Are they guaranteed to always be redeemable on a 1-to-1 basis to USDC?

It's mentioned in the AToken section of Aave's documentation:

The aTokens’ value is pegged to the value of the corresponding
supplied asset at a 1:1 ratio and can be safely stored, transferred or
traded.

However, if a significant portion of USDC in the pool is borrowed, immediate redemption (on a 1-to-1 basis to USDC) may not be possible until borrowers repay their loans or additional liquidity is added.
As, it's mentioned in the Withdraw section of Aave's documentation:

Aave Protocol allows suppliers to withdraw their supplied tokens,
including accrued interest, as long as there is sufficient unborrowed
liquidity in the reserve. The withdrawal amount is limited by the
available underlying assets, and that the user’s ability to maintain a
sufficient collateral ratio for their borrow position.

